# C++: Read a word from standard input and find out its length?

Tags: c++

I want to read a word from standard input and then find out its length in C++. I am currently using:

```
char str[80];
cout << "Enter your word: " << endl;
scanf("%s", str);
```

but cannot get the length of the word read in.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why use the C stdio facilities when you can use the C++ iostream facilities? `std::string s; std::cin >> s; unsigned len = s.length();`

Comment: any particular reason for not using the string class and cin ? also look into the csting header for length  and other string functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See how you're using `cout` to write to the standard output? In a parallel way, in modern C++, we use `cin` to read from the standard input.

Further, in modern C++, we have a real string type, called `std::string`, which we use to store strings. It comes from the `<string>` header, and it can tell us its own length.

Thus:

```
string str;
cout << "Enter your word: " << endl;
cin >> str;
int len = str.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strlen to get the length of string.

```
int len = strlen(str);
```

About std: The "not very good" of "cin >> str" is that they stop at space " ". We should use "cin.getline" instead.

```
    char name[256];

  cout << "Enter your name: ";
  cin.getline (name,256);
```